# Include npm-check in Gitlab CI

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci

I have a node project and I am creating a gitlab pipeline for that.

To check outdated packages I am running `npm-check` in the script part but its showing npm-check not found.

When I install it with `npm install npm-check` then also I get the same error. But when installing it with the `-g` option its showing permission denied.

```
install_dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install -g npm-check
    - npm-check  # Check Outdated Package
```

---

***Can anyone help me to run npm-check in my gitlab pipeline.***

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have to rights to install it globally. But it should not be not found if you install it locally first.

Remove the `-g` and make sure you are in the folder where you installed your `node_modules`.

Then you can run `npx npm-check` or `./node_modules/.bin/npm-check`.

Note that you can't directly execute `npm-check` since the binary is not in the current folder but under `node_modules/.bin/`

Comment: Thanks it works. But why the Pipeline is failing just after showing needs to be update package

Comment: If some packages needs to be updated, `npm-check` probably exited with a non-zero code, hence your pipeline failing immediately. If you don't want it to fail, you can run `npx npm-check || /bin/true` to return a 0 exit code.